# How to block incoming calls for a few minutes in iOS application?

Tags: ios

How to block the incoming calls for a few minutes in iOS application?

In my iOS application I want to block the incoming calls when the user is attending the video interview. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If your app uses CallKit then iOS will know when the user is on a call in your app and will the use the user's call forward busy/call waiting settings.  Otherwise you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the CallKit framework**

> The CallKit framework provides programmatic access to VoIP
>   functionality, as well as call blocking and identification.

Refer This Link : https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit

> It's clearly forbidden for a third-part app to block incoming
>   calls.However you can use CallKit to block unwanted calls. Your app
>   should be able to add blocked numbers.The reason Apple doesn't allow
>   you to block it is because there would be a lot of abuse and Malware
>   that would disturb user experience.

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't let you generically block all calls coming in. in iOS 10 with CallKit, you can block specific numbers ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcalldirectoryextensioncontext/1779571-addblockingentry)), but you can't block all numbers for a given time